# Python append value from dict to existing dict with two value if there is a match

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = {('a', 'b', 'c'): [4, 5], ('d', 'e', 'f'): [0, 1]}
b = {('a', 'b', 'c'): 4, ('z', 'z', 'z'): 1, ('d', 'e', 'f'): 1}
c = {key:[val,b.get(key,0)] for key,val in a.items()}
print(c)
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c'): [[4, 5], 4], ('d', 'e', 'f'): [[0, 1], 1]}
```

How do I append the value without create new value array that looks like that - `[[0, 1], 1]` ?

What I want to get is:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c'): [4, 5, 4], ('d', 'e', 'f'): [0, 1, 1]}
```

Comment: `key: val + [b.get(key,0)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> append value from dict to existing dict with two value if there is a
>   match

In your case, `a` is a *"source"* dict, `b` is a *"receiver"* dict.
Simple solution using list *concatenation*:

```
a = {('a', 'b', 'c'): [4, 5], ('d', 'e', 'f'): [0, 1]}
b = {('a', 'b', 'c'): 4, ('z', 'z', 'z'): 1, ('d', 'e', 'f'): 1}
c = {k:v + [b[k]] for k,v in a.items() if k in b}

print(c)
```

The output:

```
{('d', 'e', 'f'): [0, 1, 1], ('a', 'b', 'c'): [4, 5, 4]}
```

Comment: can you please help with one more thing, I want to do the same thing and add also the key,value if the  `a key` index[0] is `0`, for example `('d', 'e', 'f'): [0, 1]` , something like `c = {k:v + [b[k]] for k,v in a.items() if k in b or first key value is 0 a[key[0]] == 0}`, how I can do that ?

Comment: @Berlin, use this approach: `c = {k:v + [b[k]] for k,v in a.items() if k in b and v[0] == 0}`

Comment: sorry I meant I want if or, so I used `c = {k:v + [b[k]] for k,v in a.items() if k in b or v[0] == 0}` and it gives me error KeyError

Comment: `a = {('a', 'b', 'c'): [4, 5], ('d', 'e', 'f'): [0, 1], ('d', 'z', 'f'): [0, 1], ('a', 'b', 'a'): [0, 1]}`

Comment: `b = {('a', 'b', 'c'): 4, ('z', 'z', 'z'): 1, ('d', 'e', 'f'): 1}`

Comment: `c = {k:v + [b[k]] for k,v in a.items() if k in b or v[0] == 0}`

Comment: `KeyError: ('a', 'b', 'a')`

Comment: So I want the result to be `{('d', 'e', 'f'): [0, 1, 1], ('a', 'b', 'c'): [4, 5, 4], ('a', 'b', 'a'): [0, 1, 0]}` because  `('a', 'b', 'a')index[0]` value` is  == 0, and the third value should be 0, can you please help?

Comment: how that `('a', 'b', 'a'): [0, 1, 0]` ? `('a', 'b', 'a')` key has no equvalent in `b` list to join with. Also, why `('d', 'z', 'f'): [0, 1]` is not in your expected result, as it also has `0` at 1 index ?